# How do I calculate the optimal titleView width?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am using navigation with a custom `UIView` subclass that becomes my titleView. I want to ensure this is the full available width.

Logically from my `UIViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:`, this should be:

```
CGFloat width = self.width - self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.width - someConstant;
```

(I don't have a right item here.)

This would adapt, then, for different possible widths of the `leftBarButtonItem`. The catch is that `leftBarButtonItem` is `nil`, so `leftBarButtonItem.width` is always 0 (well, in the simulator anyway).

`backBarButtonItem` is also nil.

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I have this exact issue as well :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hacked this by doing the following:

```
    int vcStackSize = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] count];
    WEViewController* previousController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:vcStackSize - 2];

    NSString* previousTitle = [previousController title];

    UIFont* font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];


    lw = [previousTitle sizeWithFont:font].width + 26;
```

Nasty but it works